# How to union 2 dataframe without creating additional rows?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-zeppelin

I have 2 dataframes and I wanted to do .filter($"item" === "a") while keeping the "S/N" in number numbers.

I tried the following but it ended up with additional rows when I use union. Is there a way to union 2 dataframes without creating additional rows?

```
var DF1 = Seq(
  ("1","a",2),
  ("2","a",3),
  ("3","b",3),
  ("4","b",4),
  ("5","a",2)).
  toDF("S/N","item", "value")

var DF2 = Seq(
  ("1","a",2),
  ("2","a",3),
  ("3","b",3),
  ("4","b",4),
  ("5","a",2)).
  toDF("S/N","item", "value")
DF2 = DF2.filter($"item"==="a")

DF3=DF1.withColumn("item",lit(0)).withColumn("value",lit(0))

DF1.show()
+---+----+-----+
|S/N|item|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   a|    2|
|  2|   a|    3|
|  3|   b|    3|
|  4|   b|    4|
|  5|   a|    2|
+---+----+-----+

DF2.show()
+---+----+-----+
|S/N|item|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   a|    2|
|  2|   a|    3|
|  5|   a|    2|
+---+----+-----+

DF3.show()
+---+----+-----+
|S/N|item|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   0|    0|
|  2|   0|    0|
|  3|   0|    0|
|  4|   0|    0|
|  5|   0|    0|
+---+----+-----+

DF2.union(someDF3).show()
+---+----+-----+
|S/N|item|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   a|    2|
|  2|   a|    3|
|  5|   a|    2|
|  1|   0|    0|
|  2|   0|    0|
|  3|   0|    0|
|  4|   0|    0|
|  5|   0|    0|
+---+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left outer join your S/Ns with filtered dataframe, then use `coalesce` to get rid of nulls:

```
val DF3 = DF1.select("S/N")

val DF4 = (DF3.join(DF2, Seq("S/N"), joinType="leftouter")
              .withColumn("item", coalesce($"item", lit(0)))
              .withColumn("value", coalesce($"value", lit(0))))
DF4.show
+---+----+-----+
|S/N|item|value|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   a|    2|
|  2|   a|    3|
|  3|   0|    0|
|  4|   0|    0|
|  5|   a|    2|
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: Hi, I always thought coalesce is used for partitioning df when writing to csv, but it can also be used this way. I can't find another good example to explain this. Not in https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html. Is there another good reference to explain the use of coalesce?

Comment: It's not the coalesce of DataFrame, but the one defined in org.apache.spark.sql.functions. See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-). It works just like coalesce function in SQL, returning first non-null value.